# How do I select all div-elements where first-child is not a table

Tags: css

In my HTML there are a lot of  elements. Some div elements have an table as child element. I want to set some css properties to all div element, but differs between those with table and those without it.

My first approach:

The class property of those div-elements containing a table is set to something with 'table', so I can select them with attribute selectors as described here: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors

```
div[class*="Table"]
{ 
/* Set Properties for all div with 'table' inside class-attribute */
}
```

Unfortunately there seems to be no opposite attribute selectors.

So my first question is: Is that right or what can I do?

My next approach is, to check if one child is a table. With help of google I only find how to select e.g. first-child of an element, but not how to check, if it is a table or not.

So my question 2 and 3 is: How do I select those div elements, containing (or not containing) a table as child?

Edit: Usually the table would be first-child, but if possible I would like to check all child elements being a table or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of adding a class to `<div>`s that contain a table is the only way to do this with CSS.

There is [the `:not()` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) if that helps with this approach. It’s unsupported by IE 8 and below and Opera 9 and below, but all other browsers support it.

You can get the same effect by setting styles for `<div>`s that don’t contain tables with the `div` selector, then overriding those styles for `<div>`s with the table class, but `:not()` might make it less verbose. Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/LyLS5/

Comment: Neat, I didn't know the CSS 3 specs had a `not()` selector!

Comment: @wsanville: me either — IE support notwithstanding, I reckon it’s pretty useful.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to target parent elements with CSS (2.1 or 3). The best you can do, is manually add a class to all of the `div` tags you want to target, or use JavaScript to write your selection criteria.

If you were to use JavaScript to do this, you could easily do so with jQuery, like this:

```
$('div > :first-child').not('table').parent().addClass('notables');
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VUs8q/2/)

**Edit for comment**: If you want to select a `div` that doesn't have any tables nested, you can use the following, with the [jQuery :has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) selector:

```
$('div:not(:has(table))').addClass('notables');
```

[Working demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/VUs8q/3/)

Comment: But with this approach I am still not able to select those div-elements without a table inside, am I?

Comment: @Em1: I think you can, using [jQuery’s `:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/): `$('*:not(div:contains(table))');`

Comment: Thanks for your edit. But I will try to get along without jQuery, since there is the workaround given in the other answer. But at least now I know how I can do this using JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, honestly I would avoid using JavaScript and manually add CSS classes where you can in your HTML. I rarely rely on JavaScript for non-intranet stuff.